# Find a string, find next...the found string is at the end of the search not at the beginning

Tags: excel, vba

I am using find next a string and copy/paste adjacent cells when the string is found. I need to have the first found occurrence at the beginning, it is currently at the very end so I need to sort it afterwards. Is there a way to correct the script below to have the first found address at the beginning? [image: example]

```
Sub test()

Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 As Range
Dim StrIn As String
Dim strAdd As String

StrIn = "something"

With Worksheets(1).UsedRange

        Set rng1 = .Find(StrIn, , xlValues, xlPart, xlNext)

        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            strAdd = rng1.Address

        Set rng2 = rng1

        Do
            Set rng1 = .FindNext(rng1)
        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, rng1)

        Loop While Not rng1 Is Nothing And rng1.Address <> strAdd
    End If
End With

For Each rng3 In rng2
    Debug.Print rng3.Address
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: youve only declared `rng3` as a `Range`. `rng1` & `rng2` are unassigned and thus default to a `Variant` type variable. This is a pretty common 'gotcha moment' in vba

Comment: thanks urdearboy, but it is not working neither. Now I have it sorted in descending order...at least in continual sequency, but still not the outcome I wanted. I want to have it in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Simply swap the order that you build your `Union`

---

```
Set rng2 = Union(rng1, rng2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your search at the last cell.

eg:

```
With Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set lastCell = .Cells(.Row - 1 + .Rows.Count, .Column - 1 + .Columns.Count)
    Set rng1 = .Find(StrIn, lastCell, xlValues, xlPart, xlNext)
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it with the Ron Rosenfeld's inspirational answer. I changed the SearchDirection:=xlPrevious and left everything as it was :)

```
Set rng1 = .Find(what:=StrIn, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

Set rng2 = Union(rng2, rng1)
```

[image]